# How to find local server address for existing canvas-sketch file

Tags: terminal, localhost, canvas-sketch

How can I get the local server address from the terminal for an existing canvas-sketch file.
-- open just opens the file in the text editor.

[Example from: https://github.com/mattdesl/canvas-sketch/blob/master/docs/installation.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mcn9.jpg)

This is the address that was given when I created the file a few days ago: *http://192.168.0.108:9966/*
When I put that in my browser now it says that it can't be reached.
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go to terminal, change the directory to where your sketch file is. Then write:

canvas-sketch **whatever your sketch name is**.js --open

It will open the sketch in the browser and give the local server address.